# How to configure Webpack 4 for hot reloading html code?

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I want simply hot reload html code on index.html, but I can not figure out how to do it. It is simple to enable hot reloading for css code, but when it comes to html or js it keeps reloading page on changes. I tried many different ways to accomplish it including using contentBase/watchContentBase, polls, but nothing seems to work. Basically i want to be able run something similar to `vue init webpack`. At default vue webpack has configuration where you can hot reload everything from components including js html css. Please help!
Here is my config:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'js/app.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    hot:true,
    inline:true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject:true,
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      alwaysWriteToDisk: false
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

**app.js:**

```
import '../sass/app.scss';
import '../../index.html';
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="h1">Hello world!!!!</h1>
<script src="src/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "wptest",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A Vue.js project",
"author": "n19htz",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --color --mode development --open",
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development --progress --hide-modules",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --progress --hide-modules"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
  "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
  "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
  "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
  "webpack": "^4.20.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
}
```

}